# MySQL query works properly on Query Browser but not with msqli_query. Only retrieves one record

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've found a couple of solved questions that refers to the same type of error but those don't really solve my problem.

I'm not expert on MySQL, but I'm trying to move to the next level and do a Movies Schedule.

I'm trying to retrieve results from the MySQL db but it's not getting me the expected results from PHP, nevertheless it is retrieving the right results on the SQL browser on PHPMyAdmin.

This is the db structure:

flm_schedulechart

```
s_id    m_id    t_id    room    day     time           status
1       1       1       5       0       16:30:00       1
2       1       3       2       0       13:30:00       0
3       1       3       2       1       13:30:00       1
```

flm_movietheaters_profiles

```
t_id    name
1       Theater 1   
3       Theater 2
```

Right know if I run this sql sentence in the SQL browser on PHPMyAdmin...

```
SELECT s.s_id as 'show_id', t.name as 'theater', s.room as 'room', s.day as 'day', s.time 'time', s.status
FROM flm_schedulechart AS s
JOIN flm_movietheaters_profiles AS t
ON s.t_id = t.t_id
WHERE s.m_id=1
ORDER BY t.name
```

it retrieves:

```
show_id    theater      room    day   time        status
1          Theater 1    5       0     16:30:00    1 
2          Theater 2    2       0     13:30:00    0
3          Theater 2    2       1     13:30:00    1
```

If I use this PHP code...

These are my PHP functions:

```
function getCurrentShowingsByMovieId($con, $movie_id) {
    $result = mysqli_query( $con, "
    SELECT s.s_id as 'show_id', t.name as 'theater', s.room as 'room', s.day as 'day', s.time 'time', s.status
    FROM flm_schedulechart AS s
    JOIN flm_movietheaters_profiles AS t
    ON s.t_id = t.t_id
    WHERE s.m_id=$movie_id
    ORDER BY t.name" );
    return $result;
}

if( isset($_GET['mid']) ) {
    $r = getCurrentShowingsByMovieId( $con, $_GET['mid'] );
    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $r );
}

var_dump($r);
```

it retrieves only the first result:

```
array(6) {
["show_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["theater"]=>
string(16) "Theater 1"
["room"]=>
string(1) "5"
["day"]=>
string(1) "0"
["time"]=>
string(8) "16:30:00"
["status"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
```

Hope this is clear enough :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over your result:

```
if( isset($_GET['mid']) ) {
    $r = getCurrentShowingsByMovieId( $con, $_GET['mid'] );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($row,1) . "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Tobias Kun. I changed the WHILE for a FOREACH as it was breaking. Now it is showing: <pre>1</pre><pre>Acropolis Center</pre><pre>5</pre><pre>0</pre><pre>16:30:00</pre><pre>1</pre>, which is pretty much the same, just different markup.

Comment: Haha. Yes my markup was plainly wrong... I edited my answer so the while loop is working. Sorry for that :)

Comment: And it does the magic!, Thanks a lot. You saved my day! :). Marked as the answer.